# Regulated 3V from a LFP battery

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a small device that runs using a CR2032 battery which I would like to replace with a LFP battery. So I need something in-the-middle that adjusts the voltage. It is a very low consumption device (BLE) but still the converter should possibly "waste" as low as possible. I have found [TPS63031](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63031.pdf?ts=1697785335151&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS63031) but I have no clue how to connect it (beginner in electronics). Could someone shed some light?
Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with figure 5 and 25 of the data sheet.
Keep in mind that ... device quiescent current less than 50 μA.
Shutdown current < 1 uA.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what all this means. Do you know of a ready-to-use PCB that has 3v output using this converter?

Comment: You could try using this https://github.com/cernohorsky/TPS63031 kicad.

Comment: I have choosen another BLE device which is capable of using voltage from 2.5v to 3.6v - thank you for the help